# 503 "Service Unavailable" of Docker container with Laravel 8 in Google Cloud

Tags: php, laravel, docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I am trying to run Laravel 8 (with the database!) in Google Cloud. Deployment is done via Cloud Run with GitHub CI Trigger

**What I have done so far:**
I created all necessary Docker files for building the Docker image and container like the Dockerfile and docker-composer.yml in my apps doc root.
Because my app needs a backend and a database, I created an nginx.conf-file and an int_db.sql file, to seed the database.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm

# Arguments defined in docker-compose.yml
ARG user=hannes
ARG uid=1002

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    curl \
    libpng-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    zip \
    unzip

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install PHP extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring exif pcntl bcmath gd

# Get the latest Composer
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

# Create system user to run Composer and Artisan Commands
#RUN useradd -G www-data,root -u $uid -d /home/$user $user
RUN useradd -u 1002 -G www-data,root -d /home/$user $user
RUN mkdir -p /home/$user/.composer && \
    chown -R $user:$user /home/$user

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

USER $user
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  app:
    build:
      args:
        user: hannes
        uid: 1002
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: feedbackapp
    ports: 
      - 8080
    environment:
      # /run/docs/reference/container-contract
      PORT: ${PORT:-8080}
      K_SERVICE: feedbackapp
      K_REVISION: 0
      K_CONFIGURATION: feedbackapp
    container_name: feedbackapp-container
    restart: unless-stopped
    working_dir: /var/www/
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    networks:
      - feedbackapp

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: feedbackapp-db
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: homestead
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: homestead
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_USER: homestead
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    volumes:
      - ./docker-compose/mysql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    networks:
      - feedbackapp

  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: feedbackapp-nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./docker-compose/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    networks:
      - feedbackapp

networks:
  feedbackapp:
    driver: bridge
```

**feedbackapp.conf**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/public;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        gzip_static on;
    }
}
```

In my local Docker environment, the Laravel 8 app gets successfully built and is working well, if i request the app via http://localhost:8000/.
So I created a Cloud Run Service in Google Cloud with a CI trigger of my GitHub Repo. So every time I push my branch, my Cloud Run Service is triggered and builds my app.
The build is finished successfully in Cloud Build.

Problem: if an open the apps link, I get a 503 Service Unavailable error
[Web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPwuM.png)

[Network Status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWIwb.png)

What the log tells me:
[Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHh4q.png)

Any help is much appreciated. Stay safe.

Comment: how did you manage to fix this issue?

Comment: @Basit i switched from local development to cloud. i created a dockerfile to run the app on GCP along with a github action, which triggers the build process as soon as main branch i updated.

Answer (score 3):

There is a big confusion.

Cloud Run needs Dockerfile and that should expose proper HTTP service on port 8080.

So docker-compose is not used by Cloud Run.

1. Make sure for Cloud Run that your Dockerfile expose port 8080.
2. make sure your container also has the HTTP server and the PHP executables.

What I see at first is that your Dockerfile doesn't have a webserver and doesn't expose port 8080.

> docker-compose is only for local development.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I updated my Dockerfile so that my last lines are:  CMD php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8080
EXPOSE 8080 
Laravel itself is working now, but Laravel cant connect to the database. I get the error "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused". Guess it is, because there was no database created and so Laravel cant connect to the database. The host in my .env-file is "127.0.0.1". How i should proceed now?

Comment: @hannes_rd Cloud Run doesn't have a local database. So you need to create a Coud SQL database with public IP, and then setup the "connection" with Cloud Run, you need to use a unix socket file not 127.0.0.1 the path format is `/cloudsql/INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME` read more here: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-run

Comment: Thanks. I fixed the DB connection issue with following .env-parameters for PROD environment: 
<code>DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_SOCKET=/cloudsql/PROJECT_ID:ZONE:DB_NAME</code>